# Store account numbers as text

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this code to make sure account numbers (accounting), which are numbers, are stored as text in the range. Replacing `r.value` by `r.text` does not seem to work on whole ranges, so I need to loop. Any better idea?

```
Sub num2text(r As Range, Optional keepFormat As Boolean)
'change numbers to text, optionally leaving the numberFormat unchanged
    Dim oldFormat
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            If keepFormat Then oldFormat = c.NumberFormat   'save num fmt
            c.NumberFormat = "@"
            c.Value = c.Text
            If keepFormat Then c.NumberFormat = oldFormat   'restore num fmt
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Sub num2text_test()
    num2text Range("b10:b100")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is appending a `'` an option to retain formatting?

Comment: @RyanWildry don't think so, since my goal is to use expressions like `SUMIF(A:A,"203*",C:C)` to sum all balance of account class 203. Adding a prefix would defeat this expression.

Comment: As is 203 with a number format of `00000` will be converted to `203.`I would assign `v = c.Text`, change the number format and then assign`c.Value = v" .  This will preserve the original display values.  With these modifications `c.Value` will equal `00203`.

Comment: @TinMan good remark. I did not notice that because it is not in my use case. (in accounting, I have no class starting with 0)

Answer (score 2):

I updated the code to include @TinMan's remarks.
I also added a safety net by intersecting the range in parameter with the `UsedRange` to avoid scanning 1 million empty cells if a full column is provided as a parameter.

The most effective change is probably using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)`: I tried on about 100.000 rows in various configurations:
- all numbers: makes little difference
- just a few numbers: goes from 18 sec to 0.02 sec!

Finally I turned of recalc during the macro.

```
Sub num2text(rng As Range, Optional keepFormat As Boolean)
'change numbers to text, optionally leaving the numberFormat unchanged
    Dim oldFormat As String, t
    Dim c As Range, i As Long, r As Range
    On Error GoTo finito    'in case selection contains no numeric constants
    Set r = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each c In r
        If keepFormat Then oldFormat = c.NumberFormat   'save num fmt
        t = c.Text
        c.NumberFormat = "@"
        c.Value = t
        If keepFormat Then c.NumberFormat = oldFormat   'restore num fmt
    Next c
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
finito:
End Sub

Sub selection2text()
    num2text Selection
End Sub
```